# Why do oxides form amorphous films instead of crystalline films?

Tags: physical-chemistry, crystals, dielectric, amorphous-solids

If I oxidize a metal at room temperature, say aluminum, why does it form an amorphous material instead of crystalline $\rm Al_2O_3$?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This isn't generally true. For example rust is crystalline not amorphous. I think the question would be more precisely stated as "why do aluminium and silicon (and possibly other elements I can't think of at the moment) form amorphous oxide layers?"

Comment: @JohnRennie Do you have a source on the crystallinity of rust?

Comment: @Puk as part of an undergraduate project I scraped rust off iron and put it in an X-ray diffractometer to measure the various chemicals present in it. I can confirm from personal experience that it is crystalline. This shouldn't be surprising as the oxides of iron are slightly soluble in water and you would expect this to result in crystallisation. By contrast the oxide formed on aluminium surfaces forms a coherent layer that is very insoluble unless you raise or lower the ph.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because the volume occupied by an Al2O3 molecule is different from that occupied by two Al's. This volumetric mismatch means that you can't retain the crystalline lattice of the Al across the interface where the Al ends and the Al2O3 begins. So you'll get a jumble of Al2O3 growing at that interface.

Here you have to know that an oxide film on aluminum grows in thickness when oxygen diffuses down through the oxide to reach the aluminum underneath it- *and aluminum diffuses upwards through the oxide to reach the oxygen*. In diffusing by randomly bouncing around through an oxide structure, the diffusing aluminum atoms "forget" what the crystal orientation of their original crystallite was and instead pop out of that glassy lattice to find oxygen at random spots in the growing film.

Remember too that a chunk of aluminum is itself not monocrystalline; it consists of billions of nanoscale "crystallites" with their crystallographic axes randomly oriented, so even without the mismatch issue the aluminum surface would form randomly-oriented bodies of oxide which would not be monocrystalline "in the bulk".

Now note that the Al-to-oxygen bonds are covalent, which means they possess directivity and so you cannot morph the bond angles effortlessly into any orientation you wish. This means that once the oxide starts growing amorphously it can't revert to a crystalline structure and winds up being glassy instead.

It is possible to grow monocrystalline Al203 by other means- just not by growing a film on a piece of solid aluminum.